# validate form on button in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, validation

I have to validate a form only after click on button. Now it is working on blur and focus. How can I disable focus and blur validation and validate them on button click. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qdk5M/1941/)

```
 <form ng-app="form-example" class="row form-horizontal" novalidate>
     <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="inputEmail">Email</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <input type="email" id="inputEmail" placeholder="Email" ng-model="email" required>
        <div class="input-help">
          <h4>Invalid Email</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    <div class="control-group">
      <label class="control-label" for="inputPassword">Password</label>
      <div class="controls">
        <input ng-model="password" class="immediate-help"  required type="password" id="inputPassword" placeholder="Password">
        <div class="input-help">
          <ul>
            <li>required</strong></li>

          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
     </div>
    <div class="control-group">
      <div class="controls">
        <button class="btn">Create Account</button>
      </div>
     </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: check this link may be helpful - http://www.ng-newsletter.com/posts/validations.html

Answer (score 0):

You could have dummy class on your form level that will tell the form has been submitted or not like `ng-class="{submitted: submitted}"`, and on click of button we will use `ng-click="submitted=true"` so that after clicking on button form will have submitted class on it. Then we will apply our CSS rule for `ng-invalid` & `ng-dirty` to also consider an `.submitted` class by using concept of deep nesting of classes.

```
/* Show red border when stuff has been typed in, but its invalid */
.submitted .ng-dirty.ng-invalid {
    border-color:#ec3f41;
}
```

Other CSS rules should be taken care of this thing like I shown above.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is that you just added the validation and you're showing the message on ng-invalid ( with css). here is an example of working code to do what you want.

```
<div class="form-group col-xs-12 required" ng-class="{ 'has-error' : creditCardDetailsForm.security_code.$invalid && submitted}">
        <label class="col-lg-28 col-l-5 col-md-5 text-left font-l-20 primary control-label">Security code (CVC) </label>
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 text-left">
            <input class="form-control" name="security_code" data-stripe="cvc" ng-model="payment_details.security_code" type="number" minLength="3" required>
            <p ng-show="creditCardDetailsForm.security_code.$invalid && submitted" class="help-block">Security code is required.</p>
            <p ng-show="creditCardDetailsForm.security_code.minLength.$invalid && submitted" class="help-block">Invalid CVC.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

see, here I check if the form is invalid and the submitted has been clicked... 
in my controller:

```
    $scope.purchasePackage = function (status, response) {
    $scope.submitted = true;
    if ($scope.creditCardForm.creditCardDetailsForm.$valid) {
       //do something
    }
};
```

since you did your hide and show with CSS you can just add the class on click to the form and then do .submitted .ng-invalid so it only shows up after you have submitted.